# Typescript hints think that a value from a variable is never read in Vue template (eg v-for), except it is. TS6133

Tags: typescript, vue.js, visual-studio-code, vite, volar

The editor doesn't know the type of `brIndex` neither. If I remove `brIndex` from the `:key` property, then both eslint's `vue/no-unused-vars` (expected) and the `TS6133` show up.

[image: Example of the problem]

Here's my `tsconfig.json`:

```json
{
  "extends": "@vue/tsconfig/tsconfig.web.json",
  "include": ["env.d.ts", "src/**/*", "src/**/*.vue"],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowJs": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["./src/*"]
    }
  },

  "references": [
    {
      "path": "./tsconfig.config.json"
    }
  ]
}
```

`tsconfig.config.json`:

```json
{
  "extends": "@vue/tsconfig/tsconfig.node.json",
  "include": [
    "vite.config.*",
    "vitest.config.*",
    "cypress.config.*",
    "playwright.config.*"
  ],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "composite": true,
    "types": ["node"],
    "allowJs": true
  }
}
```

`package.json`:

```json
{
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    // scripts...
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "vue": "^3.2.45",
    "vue-router": "^4.1.6",
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@rushstack/eslint-patch": "^1.1.4",
    "@types/node": "^18.11.17",
    "@vitejs/plugin-vue": "^4.0.0",
    "@vue/eslint-config-typescript": "^11.0.0",
    "@vue/tsconfig": "^0.1.3",
    "eslint": "^8.30.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^9.8.0",
    "npm-run-all": "^4.1.5",
    "typescript": "~4.7.4",
    "vite": "^4.0.0",
    "vue-tsc": "^1.0.12"
  }
}
```

I can provide any additional info.

I am using Volar takeover mode and have `"typescript.tsdk": "node_modules/typescript/lib"` in workspace's vscode `settings.json`. My ESLint is configured properly (doesn't differ from a new project's .eslintrc.cjs) and there are no warning from my editor in that regard.

I also have my `src/vue-shim.d.ts` file although I don't know why it's needed in this configuration, but there are errors without it:

```js
declare module '*.vue' {
  import type { DefineComponent } from 'vue'
  const component: DefineComponent<{}, {}, any>
  export default component
}
```

And the `/env.d.ts` file:

```js
/// <reference types="vite/client" />
```

`vite.config.ts` has the default resolve and alias settings that's all.

The bottom bar looks normal:

[image]

The project itself runs normally and without errors.

Comment: Found out it only happens in the :key attribute if I use it in a <template> tag. If I directly use it on the <li> component the problem vanishes and types are being shown. However, whenever you have to use a <template> tag for a v-for loop which is at times very useful the issue still prevails

Comment: First I would try to update `vue-tsc` to the latest version. Sometimes they fix such bugs. If that does not solve it, I would create an issue on the volar repository

Comment: Please see: https://github.com/johnsoncodehk/volar/issues/898. there is a link to an open issue about this bug